# 1004 deletion range fail for columns

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm looking to delete a bunch of columns at the same time from a table sheet but I'm getting a Run-time Error '1004': Delete Method of Range Failed. My sheets aren't protected, but the sheet I wish to do the deletion on is a table. I've searched quite a few examples but they haven't corrected the issues, all seem to yield the same error. Here is what I have:

```
Sub Table_Creator()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Select  'cause some times excel hates me unless I use this
Worksheets("Sheet3").Paste

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A:R").Columns 

Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "ComTable"

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A:A,C:C,E:E,G:G,I:I,K:K,M:M,O:Q").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft  'errors on this line with the aforementioned error

Application.EnableEvents = True

Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFit

End Sub
```

So what am I missing? Did I add in something I shouldn't have?

Comment: You should use `ListObject`'s `ListColumns` property and delete them in loop (bacwards).

Comment: @JohnyL Could you provide an example, I've not used that before, or at least I think I haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, as per JohnyL's comment. I interpreted as "O:Q" as meaning "O,R", but if that's wrong the code will need a slight amendment.

```
Sub Table_Creator()

Dim rng As Range, c As Long, t As ListObject

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Copy .Range("A1")
    Set rng = .Range("A:R")
    Set t = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    t.Name = "ComTable"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For c = t.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1 To 1 Step -2
        t.ListColumns(c).Delete
    Next c
    t.ListColumns(t.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1).Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    t.Range.Columns.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I need the data in R Column, so will this work for that instance?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I suggest you try it and then report back if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I took a leap and it works, mostly, it didn't delete column P. Got all the others though.

Comment: I've added a line which should sort that out.

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem from *Range("A:A,C:C,E:E,G:G,I:I,K:K,M:M,O:Q").EntireColumn.* which is not a correct notation.

You are listing the ranges out for the columns, but can just use a loop with Step -2 to get between them and specify the grouped columns first (O:Q):

```
Dim i as Long
Range(Columns("O"), Columns("Q")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
For i = 13 to 1 Step -2 'Where 13 = "L" and 1 = "A"
    Columns(i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next i
```